# how to save array elements made by onDataChange

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to login to firebase and get my data and sort it in array. but I do not know how to keep this array carrying these elements to use it with (ArrayAdapter).
all I need to made an adapter with array made by onDataChange function.
like this:

```
void set_array(){
final int size=10;
final String[] list_tawsia2 = new String[size];
DatabaseReference ref1 = database.getReference().child("MyChild");
ref1.addValueEventListener(new
ValueEventListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public final void onDataChange ( @NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        
        int cc = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String txt_taw = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot1.getValue()).toString();
                list_tawsia2[cc] = txt_taw;
                cc++;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError error){
    }
});
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list_tawsia2);
 list11.setAdapter(adapter); }
```

Comment: any idea ???????

Comment: still waiting for help.

Comment: any help ???????????

Comment: still waiting >>>>>

Comment: BalusC can you take a look please

Comment: Frank van Puffelen  can you take a look please